# Using a Variable from One Function Inside Another Function then Calling It

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Write a function inCircle that takes a point and a radius as a parameter. 
# The function should return True if the point is inside the circle and False otherwise.

import math


# Function for distance equation
def pointCalc(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    distance = math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) ** 2) + ((y2 - y1) ** 2))


# Function for whether or not coordinate points are in the in/on the circle
def inCircle(point, radius):
    """Function that returns whether point is inside a circle"""
    if pointCalc.distance >= radius:
        print(f"Point ({pointCalc.x1},{pointCalc.x2}) is not in circle with radius {radius}")
    else:
        print(f"Point ({pointCalc.x1},{pointCalc.x2}) is in circle with radius {radius}")


# Prompt user for inputs on coordinate points, center, and radius
print("Enter coordinate points:")
print("---------------------------------------------")
point_x = float(input("Enter a x-coordinate point: "))
point_y = float(input("Enter a y-coordinate point: "))

print("\nEnter coordinate points for the center:")
print("---------------------------------------------")
center_x = float(input("Enter a x-coordinate point for the center: "))
center_y = float(input("Enter a y-coordinate point for the center: "))

r = float(input("\nEnter radius for the circle: "))


# Call functions
pointCalc(point_x, point_y, center_x, center_y)
inCircle(radius=r)
```

- Essentially, I went more extreme than asked because I just like complicating stuff, it makes me learn better.
- But I want to prompt the user to enter coordinate points (x, y) and then have them enter coordinate points for the center of a circle. I then want them to define a radius.
- After all of that, I want to run the coordinate points and the coordinate points for the center through the 'pointCalc' function that calculates the distance.
- I then want to use the 'distance' variable located in the 'pointCalc' function and insert it in the if/else statements in the 'inCircle' function to see if the 'radius' is greater than, less than, equal to, etc... and print out the messages in the if/else statements.
- I understand that when I call the function for 'inCircle' that I need to use the first parameter, 'point'. I just cannot figure out how to bypass it, it is not working when I try to define it when called.

Comment: You've told a lot about what you are doing, but I didn't get what your question is.

Comment: I didn't read all description but normally you can use `return distance` to send it outside function and get it as `distance = pointCalc(..)` and use this value as argument in other function `inCircle(..., distance)`

Comment: This is not how functions work, and this is not how Python works. Local variables of a function are not attributes that you can access as in `pointCalc.distance`. Functions `return` values, which are the values of the expressions that call them. I could go on but it's easier if you read up.

Comment: For any circle to be uniquely defined, you need the radius AND THE CENTRE of the cirle

Answer (score 1):

So in essence you want to pass a variable calculated in a function to another function?

Then the right way to do it (in most of the programming languages) is to `return` the value from the function. You aren't using `return` in your functions, and you can't access the variables inside of another function through a syntax like `func.variable` - a function isn't an object (kind of) and the variables it declares are destroyed once the function terminates.

So in your case:

```py
# Function for distance equation
def pointCalc(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) ** 2) + ((y2 - y1) ** 2))


# Function for whether or not coordinate points are in the in/on the circle
def inCircle(distance, radius):
    """Function that returns whether point is inside a circle"""
    if distance >= radius:
        print(f"Point ({pointCalc.x1},{pointCalc.x2}) is not in circle with radius {radius}")
    else:
        print(f"Point ({pointCalc.x1},{pointCalc.x2}) is in circle with radius {radius}")

# ...

# Call functions
d = pointCalc(point_x, point_y, center_x, center_y)
inCircle(distance=d, radius=r)
```